# How can i change new products as a new product slider

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

How can i change new products as a new product slider.

[image]

Comment: sort collection by CREATED_DATE attribute

Comment: couldn't get you

Answer (score 0):

When i was with the some what same requirements i used the following steps only difference with my requirement was i need featured product also i.e. two sliders on home page.

1) for featured product i recommend https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/featured-product-with-scroller.html

which uses box slider.

2) By using all library used by above extension you can build your slider for new product.

For this we need to make changes in

```
app\design\frontend\<package>\<theme>\template\catalog\product\widget\new\content\new_grid.phtml
```

3) Code for the above file.

```
<div class="featured">
    <div class="fhead">
        <strong>
                <span>
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?></h2>
                </span>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <?php if (($products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $products->getSize()): ?>
        <div class="items">
            <ul class="bxslider" id="bxslider1">
                <?php $count = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach ($products->getItems() as $_product) : ?>

                        <li class="productdiv">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" >
                                    <span>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(170) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" />
                                    </span>
                            </a>
                                <span class="productname">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>)"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></a>
                                </span>
                            <span class="price-con"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?></span>
                                <span class="fadd">
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </span>
                        </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="show-msg">
            <?php echo $this->__("There are no feature products."); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#bxslider1').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 4,
            slideWidth: 160,
            slideMargin: 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

in your case if you don't want to use featured product then you just need to make change in following file.

**app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\isfeatured.xml**

```
<cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="isfeatured/isfeatured" name="isfeatured" as="isfeatured"  template="isfeatured/featureblock.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
```

Just remove above code and you are done.

Comment: can i  add new file, what you told above into ->  app\design\frontend <package <theme>\template\catalog\product\widget\new\content\new_grid.phtml

Comment: Yes, by default if you are using grid mode for new product display then  it comes from app\design\frontend \base\default\template\catalog\product\widget\new\content\new_grid.phtml  you just need to place this files in your theme to make changes. check with template path hint

Comment: Actually am using Sample data theme, which is not allow any other new extensions, can you help me to do alter any change available resources.

Comment: lets continue in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39888/chat-with-jeeva

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get newly created products

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

Then loop through the products and show as a slider